# What Li-po batteries should I use to run a 32 kW BLDC motor for 10 minutes?

Tags: batteries, brushless-dc-motor

What Li-po batteries should I use for a BLDC motor that has 32 kW max. output power, a working voltage of 120 V, 225 A current draw, and that I would need to work for 10 minutes?

Comment: What does the controller need? What else are your batteries powering? Why have you chosen LiPo rather than any other options? You say it's 32kW, but the votlage current is only 29kW, which is it running at for the 10 mins?

Comment: i used Electronic Speed Control (ESC) UHV28-300 32KW to controller. I plan to use 2 packs of this type of battery "battery pack Herewin 14s 22000mah 25c" connected in series.  Do you have any other comments for me about any other type of battery?

Comment: You might find [this thesis on the construction of a battery pack for a Formula Student race car relevant.](https://webthesis.biblio.polito.it/15660/1/tesi.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not a DIY battery. Since our company does some peak sheaving & load shifting projects, we do use battery banks so called super capacitor. These are packs of around 50V, rack mount, they have LTO cells (Lithium Titanate). Practically you would need 6 such batteries 3S2P. However they are made in China, with BMS.
Another way is to DIY a pack of LTO cells, also here China is your friend - but don't be fooled with all incredible specs. If you drain the battery with 5C it won't last very long. For example 225A / 5 = approx 60Ah cell, you do need somewhere 65 such cells in series. Take a look for Yinlong 45Ah cell and do the calc of the price od such battery.

Comment: Thank you for your comments